# Let $G$ be a group. Prove that $o(xy) = o(yx)$ for all $x,y \in G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. Prove that $o(xy) = o(yx)$ for all $x,y \in G$.

**Edit:**

I wanted to prove it with basic properties of groups and orders, not with isomorphisms.

I will write the answer I worked on my notebook **using the answer by the user** that solved my problem (please stop downgrading my question / reputation, I've started learning this 2 days ago by myself, and I believe this site is about helping people to learn):

Let $m = o(xy)$.

Then:

$(xy)^m = e_G$

As $G$ is a group, there exists inverse elements for $x$ and $y$. Let $y^{-1}$ be the inverse of $y$.

As $ye_G = y$, $e_Gy^{-1} = y^{-1}$ and $yy^{-1} = e_G$ we can multiply by $y$ (by the left) and $y^{-1}$ (by the right) obtaining:

$e_G = ye_Gy^{-1}$

Now, as we know that $(xy)^m = e_G$, we can substitute $e_G$ in the previous formula:

$ye_Gy^{-1} = y(xy)^my^{-1}$

Now, we know that $(xy)^m = \overbrace{(xy)(xy)\dots(xy)}^{\text{m times}}$

So, using the previous equation:

$y(xy)^my^{-1} = y\overbrace{(xy)(xy)\dots(xy)}^{\text{m times}}y^{-1}$

And because $G$ is a group, it's associative:

$y\overbrace{(xy)(xy)\dots(xy)}^{\text{m times}}y^{-1} = \overbrace{(yx)(yx)\dots(yx)}^{\text{m times}}yy^{-1}$

And this is:

$(yx)^myy^{-1} = (yx)^me_G = (yx)^m$

So we obtained:

$e_G = (yx)^m$

And as $(xy)^m = e_G = (yx)^m$, $o(yx) = m$, and we conclude:

$o(xy) = o(yx)$ for all $x,y \in G$

I find it interesting solving this kind of problems just by using properties. Using more math structures made the problem trivial.

Comment: $yx$ is a conjugate of $xy$.

Comment: i guess you use morphisms, which i haven't learned yet. was trying to make a proof with some basic properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$ e_G=ye_Gy^{-1}=y(xy)^my^{-1}=(yx)^myy^{-1}=(yx)^m$$

---

The better argument is of course: Suppose $\phi\colon G\to G'$ is an isomorphism. Then $o(\phi(g))=o(g)$ for all $g\in G$. - And conjugation is an automorphism.

Comment: as i replied to the comment above, im trying to make a proof with some basic properties and not morphisms. your first answer was what the kind of answer i was looking for.